# Obtener tipo y número de teléfono de un contacto en Android

Tags: java, android, contenedores

Quiero obtener el número de teléfono de un contacto y también su tipo, casa, trabajo, etc...

Ahora mismo tengo una función que devuelve el número de telefono de un contacto individual.

```
public static String getNumberByContactID(Context context, String contactId) {
    Uri PHONE_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
    };
    final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
    String[] SELECTION_ARG = new String[]{contactId};

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(PHONE_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, SELECTION_ARG, null);
    String data = null;
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        data = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        c.close();
    }

    return data;
}
```

**Su uso**

`String phoneNumber = getNumberByContactID(this,<id_del_contacto>);`

Me falta lo de obtener el tipo definido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado:
Con `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE` se puede obtener el tipo de telefono que es `home, work, mobile, custom...`

Si el Tipo coincide que es de tipo personalizado pues se lee la etiqueta en `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL`

La función devuelve un array `clave,valor`

```
public static Map<String, String> getNumberByContactID(Context context, String contactId) {
    Uri PHONE_URI = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL
    };
    final String SELECTION = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?";
    String[] SELECTION_ARG = new String[]{contactId};

    Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(PHONE_URI, PROJECTION, SELECTION, SELECTION_ARG, null);
    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        int phoneType = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
        String label = null;
        switch (phoneType) {
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                label = "mobile";
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                label = "home";
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                label = "work";
                break;
            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_CUSTOM:
                label = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LABEL));
                break;
            default:
                label = "other";
        }
        data.put(
                c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)),
                label
        );
        c.close();
    }

    return data;
}
```

**Su uso**

```
Map <String,String> data = getNumberByContactID(context, contactId);
data.values().toArray()[0]; //Para obtener el número de telefono
data.keySet().toArray()[0]; //Para obtener el tipo
```